# No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: arm-linux-androideabi, React-Native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, android-ndk

So, I'm using React-Native v 0.63 on one of my old projects and when I tried to open it I get this error:

> No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: arm-linux-androideabi

Uninstalling ndk solves the problem for this old project, but then new projects do not build on android, so how can I figure this out? I tried adding ndk version in project level build.grandel:

> ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"

and using it in App level build.grandle:

> ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion

But its not working, how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

In my case problem was solved by installing ndk version 20.1.5948944 and then specifying pass to in in /android/local.properties:

> ndk.dir=/Users/almag3st/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/20.1.5948944

Also make sure to remove any specific ndkVersion from build.grandels.